# Extend States for Model in Odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I want to extend the "state" column of the mrp.production model. There was an example I found in https://www.odoo.com/de_DE/forum/how-to/developers-13/how-to-extend-fields-selection-options-without-overwriting-them-21529 but it seems to not work in odoo 11.

i.e. the `__init__` signature changed to `__init__(self, pool, cr)` (guessing this from the error trace that I saw referencing `model.__init__(pool, cr)`)

```
from odoo import models, fields
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class mrp_production(models.Model):
   _inherit = 'mrp.production'

   def __init__(self, pool, cr):
       super(mrp_production, self).__init__(pool, cr)
       states = self._columns['state'].Selection

       _logger.debug('extend state of mrp.production')

       state_other = ('other_state', 'My State')
       if state_other not in states:
           states.append(state_other)
```

The Error I'm receiving is:

`AttributeError: 'mrp.production' object has no attribute '_columns'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to extend the `__init__`. Please look into the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#inheritance-and-extension) to get a first look how to extend odoo business models.

For your example the correct code:

```py
from odoo import models, fields

class MrpProduction(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mrp.production'

    state = fields.Selection(
        selection_add=[('other_state', 'My State')])
```

Comment: thanks - missed the selection_add in the documentation

Comment: It was introduced with the new API in Odoo 8 and can only used on "new" style fields, which is the only style since Odoo 10.

Comment: is there an option to define where in the Selection the new entries should be added? (ie before the "done" state)

Comment: As far as i know -> no. That would be possible by using `selection` instead and defining the complete selection plus your new selection entries.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you follow is for old API.
You can try
https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/extend-selection-odoo-10/

```
from odoo import models, fields, api, _
 class HrEmployee(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.employee' 
    gender = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('transgender', 'Transgender')])
```